# $3 \times3$ matrices with rank $1$ or $2$ are manifolds

Tags: matrices, differential-geometry, manifolds, matrix-rank, rank-1-matrices

> Let $M, N \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be sets of matrices $3 \times 3$ with rank $1$ and $2$, respectively. Show that $M$ and $N$ are manifolds such that dim $M=5$ and dim $N=8$.

---

I have thought about using the determinant function $ \det: \mathbb{R}^{n^{2}} \to \mathbb{R}$ but i have problems when i deal with $f^{-1}(0)$.

Comment: $\det A = 0$ if and only if the rank of $A$ is *at most* $2$.

Comment: why you don't accept my answer (see below) ??

Comment: @ne3886 Excuse me friend, I've been busy. Could I send you the process I did to resolve the point? In the same way, thanks for the answer, it helped me a lot

Comment: Where does this come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's refine the precedent answer.

Let $$M_{ij} = \left\{ A = (A_1, A_2, A_3)^T \in M\mid a_{ij} \ne 0\right\}$$
and $\varphi_{ij}: M_{ij} \to X_j\times \mathbb{R}^2$ be the chart,
where $X_1 = \mathbb{R}^{\ast}\times\mathbb{R}^2$, $X_2 = \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^{\ast}\times\mathbb{R}$ and $X_3 = \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^{\ast}$. And $\varphi_{ij}(A) = \left(a_{i1}, a_{i2}, a_{i3}, (\frac{a_{kj}}{a_{ij}})_{k\ne i}\right)$.

N.B. why $\left(\frac{a_{kj}}{a_{ij}}\right)_{k\ne i}$: for exampel if $A = (A_1 A_2 A_3)^T\in M_{11}$ we know that $A_2 = \lambda_2 A_1,\, A_3 = \lambda_3 A_1$ for some $\lambda_1,\lambda_2\in\mathbb{R}$. Because $a_{11} \ne 0$, we deduce $\lambda_1 = \frac{a_{21}}{a_{11}}$; idem for $\lambda_2$.

It is clear that $X_j\times\mathbb{R}^2$ is an open of $\mathbb{R}^5$ and $\varphi_{ij}\circ\varphi_{lk}^{-1}: X_j\times\mathbb{R}^2\cap X_k\times\mathbb{R}^2 \to X_j\times\mathbb{R}^2\cap X_k\times\mathbb{R}^2$
is a $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$ gluing map. so M is a manifold of dimension 5.

The same for N:
Just consider $$N_{ij} = \left\{ A \in N\mid \text{the submatrix of } A \text{ resulting of removing ith row and jth column is of determinant non null} \right\}$$

For example $N_{33} = \left\{A\in N\mid a_{11}a_{22} - a_{21}a_{12}\ne 0\right\}$. Because $A= \left(A_1 A_2 A_3\right)^T\in N$, we know there exist $\lambda_{1},\lambda_{2}\in\mathbb{R}$, s.t. $A_3 = \lambda_1 A_1 + \lambda_2 A_2$. So in particular $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ are solutions to the equation system:
$$
a_{11}\lambda_1 + a_{12}\lambda_2 = a_{13}\\
a_{21}\lambda_1 + a_{22}\lambda_2 = a_{23}
$$

so by Cramer rules we have:
$$\lambda_1 = \frac{\det\begin{pmatrix}a_{13} & a_{12}\\a_{23} &a_{22}\end{pmatrix}}{\det\begin{pmatrix}a_{11} & a_{12}\\a_{21} &a_{22}\end{pmatrix}} = \frac{a_{13}a_{22} - a_{23}a_{12}}{a_{11}a_{22} - a_{21}a_{12}}$$

$$\lambda_2 = \frac{\det\begin{pmatrix}a_{11} & a_{13}\\a_{21} &a_{23}\end{pmatrix}}{\det\begin{pmatrix}a_{11} & a_{12}\\a_{21} &a_{22}\end{pmatrix}} = \frac{a_{11}a_{23} - a_{21}a_{13}}{a_{11}a_{22} - a_{21}a_{12}}$$

We define, for example, for $A =\left(A_1 A_2 A_3\right)^T\in N_{33}$
$$\varphi_{33}: N_{33} \to  U_{33} \times \mathbb{R}^{2}\\
\varphi_{33}(A) = \left(A_1, A_3, \lambda_1, \lambda_2\right) =
\left(A_1, A_2, \frac{a_{13}a_{22} - a_{23}a_{12}}{a_{11}a_{22} - a_{21}a_{12}},\frac{a_{11}a_{23} - a_{21}a_{13}}{a_{11}a_{22} - a_{21}a_{12}}\right)
$$
where $U_{33} = \left\{(A_1 A_2)^T \in\mathcal{M}_{3\times 2}\mid a_{11}a_{22} - a_{21}a_{12} \ne 0\right\}$.

The same goes for all $N_{ij}$. It is clear that $U_{ij}\times\mathbb{R}^2$ is an open of $\mathbb{R}^8$ and the gluing maps:
$$\varphi_{ij}\circ\varphi_{kl}^{-1}: U_{ij}\times\mathbb{R}^2\cap U_{kl}\times\mathbb{R}^2 \to U_{ij}\times\mathbb{R}^2\cap U_{kl}\times\mathbb{R}^2$$ are $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$ maps.

This proves that $N$ is manifold of dimension $8$.

Comment: I apology for my ignorance, but I don't know the "gluing map" means. I still can't understand why we can deduce from $M_1, M_2, M_3$, as these were defined above in the first comment, that $M$ is a manifold. For me is totally clear that each $M_i$ and each $M_i \cap M_j$  are manifolds. I'd like to see that $M_i =M\cap V_i$ with $V_i$ open in $\mathbb{R^9} $ for each $i=1,2,3$. In this way, I could conlude easily that M is a manifold.

Comment: @3435, may be it is complicated to prove the claim in general or it is false! I have added the details for the proof that $N$ is a manifold. This post should be the accepted answer not the other post!!!!!

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 3):

For $A$ a $3\times 3$ matrix, we denote $A = \left(A_1, A_2, A_3\right)$.
Let $M$ be matrices of $\mathcal{M}_{3\times 3}(\mathbb{R})$ of rank 1.

We have $M = M_1 \cup M_2 \cup M_3$, where
$$M_1 = \left\{ A = (A_1, A_2, A_3) \mid A_1 \ne 0_{\mathbb{R}^3}, A_2 = \lambda_{2} A_1, A_3 = \lambda_{3} A_1 \text{ for } \lambda_2,\lambda_3\in\mathbb{R}\right\} $$

$$M_2 = \left\{ A = (A_1, A_2, A_3) \mid A_2 \ne 0_{\mathbb{R}^3}, A_1 = \lambda_{1} A_2, A_3 = \lambda_{3} A_2 \text{ for } \lambda_1,\lambda_3\in\mathbb{R}\right\} $$

$$M_3 = \left\{ A = (A_1, A_2, A_3) \mid A_3 \ne 0_{\mathbb{R}^3}, A_1 = \lambda_{1} A_3, A_2 = \lambda_{2} A_3 \text{ for } \lambda_1,\lambda_2\in\mathbb{R}\right\} $$

Every $M_i,\,i=1,2,3$ is a manifold of dimension $5$ ($M_i \cong \left(\mathbb{R}^3\setminus \{0_{\mathbb{R}^3}\}\right) \times \mathbb{R}^2$ and also $M_i\cap M_j$
is a manifold of dimension $5$. so $M$ is manifold of dimension $5$.

Let $\det: \mathbb{R}^9 \to \mathbb{R}$ be the determinant.
we have $N = \det^{-1}(0) \setminus M$ and $\det^{-1}(0)$ is manifold of
dimension $8$.

Comment: why do you say that $M_i \cap M_j$ manifold implies $M$ manifold?...why is $N-M$ a manifold?...

Comment: thanks for the answer, it helped me a lot.

Comment: @3435 look to the other detailed answer.

Comment: No, matrices of determinant $0$ do not form a manifold.